# Why is this type not serializable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

I'm trying to determine why this type isn't serializable (as tested by `Type.IsSerializable()`)

```
<Serializable()> _
Public MustInherit Class WellKnownInstanceCollectionWithTypedId(Of T As WellKnownInstanceWithTypedId(Of IdT), IdT)
    Inherits ReadOnlyCollection(Of T)

    Public Sub New(ByVal list As IList(Of T))
        MyBase.New(list)
    End Sub


    Public Function GetById(ByVal id As IdT) As T
        Return Me.FirstOrDefault(Function(item) item.Id.Equals(id))
    End Function

End Class
```

I know it has something to do with my `GetById` function, because if I remove that everything is fine. Can someone tell me what I need to change to have this type be serializable?

**Update:**

When I change my `GetById` implementation as such, everything is fine. Obviously this has something to do with Linq (as suggested below) - can anyone give me further details on why this is so?

```
    Public Function GetById(ByVal id As IdT) As T
        For Each i In Me
            If i.Id.Equals(i) Then
                Return i
            End If
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: try to serialize it, it will throw exception with more details

Comment: I wanted to confirm it is not the use of LINQ (`FirstOrDefault`) but the use of a closure (`Function` accessing a local variable, or in this case a parameter). However I am not able to reproduce your problem: `GetType(WellKnownInstanceCollectionWithTypedId(Of ,)).IsSerializable` returns `True` for me in .NET 3.5 with your original definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be related to the lambda expression (`Function`) in `GetById`.
Try converting it to an `AddressOf` call to see if the background closure VB.NET is creating for you is getting in the way of serialization.

<sub>*(Promoting comment to answer)*</sub>
In your complete code, to test whether it *is* LINQ or the closure, just change your original code to `Return Me.FirstOrDefault(False)`.

I believe that will make it serialisable again. If so, you can use `AddressOf id.Equals` instead of `Function(Item)...` which has the same semantics unless you wanted to cater for a null (`Nothing`) `id`.

Comment: Very strange...when I replaced my GetById impl to use interation instead of linq it became serializable...I'd love to know further reasoning behind this, though.

Comment: I actually ended up externalizing my linq functions as specifications and had by GetById function call these instead (I had other cases where serialization was failing due to this); very strange, but I now have everything working as expected - thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 2):

Serializable types need to have a default constructor

Comment: ReadOnlyCollection does have one, so this isn't the issue.

Comment: @DanP But constructors are not inherited so this may still be an issue.

Comment: well, in this case, it doesn't seem to matter. Removing the inital impl of my GetById method results in the class being serializable.